# Laravel dispatch with Closure suddenly returns an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting this `Opis\Closure\ClosureStream::stream_set_option is not implemented!` when I'm running a closure using the dispatch helper.

```
        dispatch(function () use ($done) {
            foreach ($done as $order) {
              try{
                Log::info("Some code");
              }catch(\Exception $e){
                continue;
              }
            }
        });
```

It's been years since I've worked with PHP and I'm really stuck on this part.

I'm using vagrant with laravel 5.8 and my PHP 7.4.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I encountered this error in `botman` laravel. This exception is due to PHP 7.4. I solved this error by downgrading my PHP version from 7.4 to 7.1

Comment: You'd expect that while the version is increasing the features also improves but that's not the case :,( - Thanks Guys